# ESP authentication on Firebase with Google credentials

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, esp32

I am developing an IoT device with a flutter app and an ESP32.
For that, I created an App (Flutter/Dart) with a Google Firebase Real Time Database. The authentication in the app and therefore with Firebase RTDB is possible with the Google login only. The login and reading of data from RTDB works fine in the mobile app. But when I try to connect and read data from the RTDB with the ESP I am not able to login or read any data. I cannot find any way on how to login with google credentials on the ESP and then use the RTDB data.
Does anyone has an idea?
I only find solutions for anonymous/email password authentications for ESP but I want to have a save connection from user and ESP device.

The security rules in my RTDB are only letting registered and logged-in users read the content.

This is my current ESP32 code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#if defined(ESP32)
  #include <WiFi.h>
#elif defined(ESP8266)
  #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#endif
#include <Firebase_ESP_Client.h>


#include "addons/TokenHelper.h"
#include "addons/RTDBHelper.h"

#define WIFI_SSID "WIFI-name"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "WIFI-pw"

#define API_KEY "API-key"  



#define USER_EMAIL "Google-mail-address"
#define USER_PASSWORD "Google-mail-password"

// Define Firebase objects
FirebaseData Firebase_dataObject;
FirebaseAuth authentication;
FirebaseConfig config;


String uid;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi ..");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print('.');
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();

  config.api_key = API_KEY;
  authentication.user.email = USER_EMAIL;
  authentication.user.password = USER_PASSWORD;

  Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);
  Firebase_dataObject.setResponseSize(4096);
  config.token_status_callback = tokenStatusCallback;
  config.max_token_generation_retry = 5;

  Firebase.begin(&config, &authentication);

  Serial.println("Getting User UID");
  while ((authentication.token.uid) == "") {
    Serial.print('.');
    delay(1000);
  }
  uid = authentication.token.uid.c_str();
  Serial.print("User UID: ");
  Serial.print(uid);
}

void loop(){

}
```

Thanks